# Unable to build AngularJS using grunt

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm installing the AngularJS and stuck at following step:

grunt package.

Error is as follows:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read CDN version, are you offline or has the CDN not been properly pushed?
>>     at Object.module.exports (D:\angular.js\Gruntfile.js:21:11)
>>     at loadTask (D:\angular.js\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:325:10)
>>     at Task.task.init (D:\angular.js\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:437:5)
>>     at Object.grunt.tasks (D:\angular.js\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:120:8)
>>     at Object.module.exports [as cli] (D:\angular.js\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:38:9)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rnaguban\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:44:20)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
>>     at startup (node.js:139:18)
>>     at node.js:968:3

Running tasks: package
Warning: Task "package" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: are you connected to internet ? "Unable to read CDN version, are you offline"

Comment: You probably shouldn't rely on a CDN for local development and also `Task "package" not found`

Comment: @Raghuveer I'm connected to internet

Comment: You probably did't remember to switch to the correct branch...this is what i forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I also met this problem like this:**

```
CDN version (remote): No version found. Current version (remote): v1.5.7 Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read CDN version, are you offline or has the CDN not been properly pushed? Warning: Task "package" not found. Use
--force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I checked the angular's source code ,Found in the 'Gruntfile.js' ,line20 it throw the Error

> Unable to read CDN version, are you offline or has the CDN not been properly pushed?

, so comment this code to solve your problem.

```
  //if (versionInfo.cdnVersion == null) {
  //  throw new Error('Unable to read CDN version, are you offline or has the CDN not been properly pushed?');
  //}
```

this can make the building success.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should set environment variable `NG1_BUILD_NO_REMOTE_VERSION_REQUESTS` at first. For example, in Windows:

```
set NG1_BUILD_NO_REMOTE_VERSION_REQUESTS=1
```